# Query Google Core Reporting API to get list of Google Analytics events in order they were sent out

Tags: google-analytics, google-reporting-api

I am writing an Android app and I am tracking some events through Google Analytics. Most of those events are interactions of the user with the app.

I am querying Google Core Reporting API to get detailed information about those events.

I am interested in finding out, for a particular session, the order in which the events happened. I have tried sorting the events by date, hour and minute, ("ga:date, ga:hour, ga:minute") but this is not good enough as some events happen within seconds of each other.

Is there any way I can get the list of events sorted by the order in which they were sent out?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Send a time stamp with the event. I don't believe it's possible to get hit-level data i.e. time of event using basic GA. I believe this is only available via Session Export for Premium clients.

Comment: Thank you @Blexy, your suggestion sounds good, I will implement it that way.